# How do I switch tabs based on incremental search in vim?

Tags: performance, vim, tabs, switching

For example, let's say I have three tabs open in vim:

```
1: nice_program.c
2: something_fun.h
3: super_script.sh
```

So if I hit some magic modifier key, and then type 'n' and hit enter I change tab to tab 1. Likewise, typing 'su' instead will navigate me to tab 3 instead.

Is such behavior possible? There are so many vim extensions, and I dont really get the whole vim extension lingo.

BTW, I am using gVim on XP and MacVim on OS X. Preferably the solution will work on both...

EDIT:

Note that I only want the incremental search to search across the names of the open tabs. That is, it's not supposed to actually search inside the tabs themselves.

Also, I never use buffers, it's tabs that I want this working for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the wording of the question it seems that you take the idea of tabs in
Vim not the way it is supposed to be taken by design of this feature.  A Vim
tab page is not a form of a buffer or a window, it is a window layout
container, instead.  No wonder there is no built-in way for switching to a tab
by the name of a buffer that is active (or the only one in its tab page, or
special in some other way).  Semantically, that is switching to a buffer, not
a tab (but tab could be switched in order to show a buffer, if it is
necessary).

To switch to a buffer by its name use the `:sbuffer` command (`:sb`, for
short).  It is not necessary to type the whole buffer name each time, since
the command has auto-completion.  Usually one have to type only few letters of
a name to uniquely identify a buffer (the same way as you described
incremental search in the question).

By default, Vim open the requested buffer displacing one in the current
window.  This behavior is governed by the `switchbuf` option.  One of the
choices (called `usetab`) provided by that option allows to switch to a window
in another tab page if that window contains the buffer to edit.  This is
exactly what suits your manner of work with tab pages.

To summarize, change the switching behavior as follows

```
:set switchbuf=usetab
```

and use the `:sb` command to open a buffer by typing a few letters of its name
and using <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion.

Comment: The usetab option for switchbuf doesn't seem to be valid. I can't input it in gVim at least...

Comment: @c00kiemonster:  It's valid for sure (see `:help switchbuf` in your Vim).  What do you mean by saying that you "can't input it"?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: well it doesn't seem to work. or at least not as i expect it too. if i do :b it just changes the present tab to another buffer, it doesn't switch to any other tab

Comment: @ib that's actually a good solution, if you put it together with my proposal you get nice tab navigation. +1 (and updated my .vimrc)

Comment: @c00kiemonster:  Oh, I'm sorry.  I have made a mistake when refer to the switching command from memory.  `:b` does not respect `switchbuf`, `:sb` does.  See the update.

Comment: @romainl:  I've mentioned the wrong command by mistake, since I never work with buffers the way c00kiemonster does.  The solution works with any buffer switching command that respects `switchbuf`.

Comment: @sa125:  As a matter of fact, having a list of all buffers before one's eyes is not so necessary because of completion.  However, you are right, if the intelligent list of buffer names provided by completion is not sufficient for you, `:ls|b` (instead of plain `:b`) or `:ls|sb` (in place of `:sb`) probably helps.

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet I picked up in vim wiki to switch between open buffers (mapped to `F5`):

```
" switch between numbered buffers
:nnoremap <F5> :buffers<CR>:buffer<Space>
```

(put in your .vimrc file or whichever dotfile you use).

As for incremental search across open buffers, whenever I look up something using either `/[something]` or with `*`/`#` on current word, it's automagically also highlighted in other buffers/tabs. Then I can switch buffers and hit `n` or `N` to move between matches in the currently viewed buffer. That's already baked into Vim.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yea I've seen a lot of blog posts covering stuff like this. I'm only interested in tabs, and only the tab names themselves, not inside the actual tabs... Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 1):

The `:set switchbuf=usetab` solution given by ib never worked for me for whatever reason (even without loading plugins or my .vimrc) but `:tab drop name-of-file` works just the way you want (I found it [on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages)).

Make it a custom mapping to save a few keystrokes with `nnoremap <leader>t :tab drop`.

Also I second ib's comment on the right and wrong way to use tabs in Vim.

Comment: Never really got it to work properly. As it's likely that Vim's buffer/tab implementation predates tabs as modern UI elements (like in a web browser for example). Personally though, the multiple pages (buffers) within one window approach reminds me far too much of Emacs.  *Shudders*. But changing that approach would probably upset a great deal of venerable Vim veterans. A compromise would perhaps to do it the chrome way, ie to compartmentalize each and every tab, and then make switching between them quick easy.

Comment: FWIW, i ended up just putting these in my .gvimrc `nnoremap <C-h> :tabprevious<CR>` and `nnoremap <C-l> :tabnext<CR>`. Works fine for me, but I would of course prefer what I initially dreamed of. YMMW

Comment: That is not a general solution.  First, the `:drop` command is available only if Vim is compiled with a GUI.  Second and more important, this command is not for switching buffers, it is for opening files.  Therefore, auto-completion for this command suggests not the names of open buffers, but filenames.  And that only fact makes it significantly less useful.

Comment: @c00kiemonster:  What matters is switching between buffers (i.e. files for editing) and not between tab pages.  And it is quick and easy already (as it is shown in my answer), just tell Vim what *buffer* do you want to see.  After all, you want to switch to a *file*, don't you?

Comment: @c00kiemonster:  By the way, there are `gt` and `gT` shortcuts for switching to the next and the previous tab page respectively.  And if you give a number before one of those commands, you can switch to the tab page with that given number (for example, `4gt` open the tab page number 4).  For solution that you "initially dreamed of" see my answer.

Comment: @ib: no I am interested in switching the tab (and whatever buffer that particularly tab is showing at the moment). `gt` and `gT` just didn't fall very natural to my hands if you catch my drift, your `:sb` worked the most to my liking.

Comment: @ib, cOOkiemonster, I did a bit of experimenting with my answer and it won't work in real world cases because of the filename auto-completion limitation pointed by ib. It works if the only buffers loaded in your tabs are in the same directory but it breaks as soon as you open a file from somewhere else. But allow me to repeat that tabs in vim don't work the way you want them to work, you'll have better luck NOT trying to work against the grain, here. You are supposed to use splits and buffers to edit multiple files and switch between them. Tabs are more like "perspectives" in an IDE.